# LINQ for removing elements that are started with other element from list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list `List<string>` with some paths.

```
C:\Dir\Test\
C:\MyDir\
C:\YourDir\
C:\Dir\
```

I want to go through all the elements (using LINQ) and remove entries that are started with other element from my list.

In my example `C:\Dir\Test\` starts with `C:\Dir\` - so I want to remove `C:\Dir\Test\`.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: They all start with C:\ wouldn't this remove all but one?

Comment: Only if `C:\\` is in the list @Sayse

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov it's just a simplified case. I need an idea from this problem to solve my more complex issue

Comment: @Sayse Please look an example. There is no `C:\` on the list. If it was, all the entries would be removed.

Comment: Oh your treating them as the exact strings, then yeah what Marcin wrote

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`List<T>.RemoveAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) method:

```
sourceList.RemoveAll(x => sourceList.Any(y => x != y && x.StartsWith(y)));
```

Comment: All `x` will have item matching iteself in the sourceList.

Comment: What if same string is in twice

Comment: At that point, it will occur in the list and so be removed. As he asked right?

Comment: `RemoveAll` returns an `int`, hence your `ToList()` call is wrong and should be removed.

Comment: @Tikkes nope because it will equal

Comment: This is O(n^2) solution

Comment: Just some caveats: paths in windows aren't case sensitive while this code is. Also, the StartsWith approach is safe only if paths end with backslash.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
myInitialList.RemoveAll(x =>myInitialList.Any(q => q != x && q.StartsWith(x)));
```

Or if you want to keep the original list, this is a way to get all the records that do not match your criteria:

```
List<string> resultList = myInitialList.Except(x => myInitialList.Any(q => q != x && q.StartsWith(x)));
```

Comment: will also remove `C:\Dir\ ` from example because `C:\Dir\Test\ ` and `C:\Dir\ ` starts with `C:\Dir\ ` :)

Comment: Ohw yes, indeed, same thing Marcin has at first. Will edit answer

Comment: What about duplicates?

Comment: This is O(n^2) solution

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
 mylist =  mylist.Where(a => mylist.All(b => b == a || !a.StartsWith(b)))
                 .Distinct()
                 .ToList();
```

This will return a new list where there isn't another item in the list that it starts with.

It has the extra check to allow returning the value where there string is the same, otherwise all items would be removed from the list.

Finally the distinct call means that two occurrences of the same string are removed.

Building on nsinreal's comment and solution you could do something like

```
myList = myList.OrderBy(d => d)
.Aggregate(new List<string>(),  
    (list, item) => {
        if (!list.Any(x => item.StartsWith(x)))
            list.Add(item);

        return list;
    }).ToList();
```

This reduces the complexity of the solution by reducing the size of the search list for each test.  It still requires an initial sort.

Personally I find this alternative solution harder to read and my first answer is more expressive the problem to solve.

Comment: This is `O(n^2)` solution.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way is IMO to sort the paths, then iterate them and return only the ones not starting as one of the previous, i.e. :

```
public static IEnumerable<string> 
GetRootPathsOfSet(this IEnumerable<string> paths)
{
    var sortedSet = new SortedSet<string>(paths,
                                          StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    string currRoot = null;
    foreach (var p in sortedSet)
    {
        if (currRoot == null ||
           !p.StartsWith(currRoot, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            currRoot = p;
            yield return currRoot;
        }
    }
}
```

Some notes:

- All the paths MUST terminate with a trailing back-slash, otherwise the `StartsWith` approach is not safe (e.g. `C:\Dir` and `C:\Directory`)
- This code uses case-insensitive comparison
- I'm not using pure LINQ here, but it's an extension method